# How to post form data directly to Email Id

Tags: php, html

I want to post the careers form directly on email using HTML5. To post the form directly on my email id and i used syntax

```
    <form action:"mailto:web@domain.com" method="post" enc type="text/plain">
    </form>
```

but it does not work properly. Please tell me how i links form directly with email id.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`<form action="mailto:web@domain.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">`

instead of

`<form action:"mailto:web@domain.com" method="post" enc type="text/plain">`

:-)

Comment: I did this also but same problem occurs.

Comment: Which problem occurs, exactly? Can you post firebug or similar tool output?

Comment: When i click on the send button pop up window opens in which they ask the mailing through for eg. mail through outlook, gmail etc. and i don't this to visible to users.

Answer (score 0):

like below:

```
 <form action="mailto:myforms@mydomain.com" enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="location.href='thanks.html';" >
```

**Refer:** http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/email-form-mailto.html

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form action="mailto:web@domain.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
</form>
```

You just wrote enctype wrong. Hope this helps :)